# How to add a parameter to manipulate in Maxima?

Tags: maxima

So, I'm trying to do a nice interactive graph in Maxima, and encountered a problem. I'd like to have a slide where I can choose n, specify its range and then plot something like Sin(nx) without having to go back and changing line each time. Quite obviously, with such advanced and popular program, this needs to be achievable, but I somehow cannot figure out how.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a plot with sliders in maxima?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161305/how-to-create-a-plot-with-sliders-in-maxima)

Comment: No, it is not the duplicate. For some insane reasons, I cannot find a single case of someone using sliders with plot2d, and all of them only with plotdf.

Comment: Like, I'm trying to do this, mimicking the example in the maxima pdf plot2d([x^2+k], [x,-2,3], [parameters,"k=2"],[sliders,"k=1:5"]); and it spews errors. Why.

Comment: It's so simple in mathematica, you just use Manipulate. Why does it have to be that cryptic here?!

Comment: And before some smarta** says "just use mathematica", NO, this is a basic thing that's supposed to be easy in all programs.